# CSS keeps flagging this line

Tags: html, css

I am new to writing CSS. I am a marketing student taking an HTML and CSS class.  I cant seem to figure out why it's flagging this code.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

It flags LINE 9  and im really confused on why. It says unexpected colon at line 9 col 15.

-help!

Comment: i don't think that error come from css.

Comment: it's better if you  to post your complete code

Comment: The error should not be coming from this CSS code, it might be something else. It would be great if you can post the complete code, at least the first 15 lines of the file where it is flagging the error..

Comment: CSS would never give such error. pls post code to inspect